# Spotify link button do not open Spotify but download the installer again, even if Spotify is already installed

Tags: button, hyperlink, download, spotify

I just used your Spotify link button maker to add to my website.
Unfortunately, when I click on it, instead of opening Spotify to the right album as I thought it would do, it downloads the installer again, even if I alerady have Spotify up and running.
You can check it on my website www.alan-a.com if you want.

I use a MacBook and Google Chrome to do so and all my softwares are up to date.

Thank you,

Alan A.

Comment: Probably you should post on superuser

Answer (score 0):

This will be a problem with your own local setup — all Play Buttons work the same, unless you modified it after generating it on our site. I just tried your website, and it works fine on my machine.